# Set Resource drawable to BitmapDrawable

Tags: android, bitmap

I have derived a class BitmapDrawable in android for some reason but I want to know how can I assign a resource id ( I mean the icon in a drawable folder ) to My class ?

as its super constructor as for a Resources object ( but my class doesnt have access to 
getResources() ) so how can I set the Resource id to BitmapDrawable.

> But i think getting getResources won't help me as BitmapDrawable
>   doesn't have  (Resources res , int id) constructor

```
static class DownloadedDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
        private final WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask> bitmapDownloaderTaskReference;

        public DownloadedDrawable(BitmapDownloaderTask bitmapDownloaderTask) {

            bitmapDownloaderTaskReference =
                new WeakReference<BitmapDownloaderTask>(bitmapDownloaderTask);
        }

        public BitmapDownloaderTask getBitmapDownloaderTask() {
            return bitmapDownloaderTaskReference.get();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the image from an activity when you create your bitmap. Alternatively you can use

```
getContext().getResources()
```

to get the resources from an class

Comment: My Class is not inside an activity

Comment: Where is it so ? The this.getContext().getRseources() can work I think.

Comment: i Know that will work but my class is a separate one and runs with a Async